# Constructing a reflexive transitive closure in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Lets say I want to form a ranking of entities in a hypothetical league. Each player would be represented by a node in a graph, and would have multiple child nodes, that would represent the contestants they had beaten.

My goal is to create an exact ranking (if it's possible in that case), where I would use transitivity to determine a relationship between 2 players, even if they haven't played each other:

Like this:

```sql
A vs. B (1:0)
B vs. C (1:0)
/* will resolve in: */
A vs. C (1:0)
```

I have implemented this graph like this:

```
unordered_map<string, set<string>> graph;
```

Where the `key` is the name of the contestant and the `value` is a `set` of the contestant this contestant has **directly** beaten.

My ideal outcome would be a `map<string, int>`, where the string would represent a contestant, and every "point" they would gain by **either beating an opponent transitively, or directly** would be a +1 value represented by the int.

To fill this graph up with correct information is a relatively easy task, but what would be the most efficient way to actually **create a relation between every node** depending on their child nodes?
I have tried this fairly sad looking linear approach, but it simply does not work:

```cpp
        // Apply the reflexive transitive closure to the graph
        unordered_set<string> nodes;
        for ( const auto &entry : graph ) {
            nodes.insert( entry.first );
        }
        for ( const auto &k : nodes ) {
            for ( const auto &i : nodes ) {
                for ( const auto &j : nodes ) {
                    if ( graph[i].count( k ) == 1 && graph[k].count( j ) == 1 ) {
                        graph[i].insert( j );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Check if the graph is strongly connected
        for ( const auto &entry : graph ) {
            unordered_set<string> reachable;
            queue<string> node_queue;
            node_queue.push( entry.first );
            reachable.insert( entry.first );
            while ( !node_queue.empty() ) {
                string u = node_queue.front();
                node_queue.pop();
                for ( const auto &v : graph[u] ) {
                    if ( !reachable.count( v ) ) {
                        reachable.insert( v );
                        node_queue.push( v );
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( reachable.size() != graph.size() ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to help me with my approach.

Comment: I don't know any C++, but you are looking for a relation between x and y whenever y is in the subtree spanned by node x (if you have cycles this transitive approach does not make sense). So you can do a bottom up traversal of the tree and add the relations of a child to its parent.

Comment: A topological sort will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need your algorithm to work when the graph is acyclic, then you should start with a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  If you must actually construct the complete transitive closure, then just process the vertices in reverse topological order, connecting every vertex to its 2nd-level descendants.

If you need to construct the transitive closure even when the graph has cycles, then you can use the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

Normally, that algorithm is used to calculate all-pairs shortest paths.  When you don't actually need path lengths, it is a little simpler:

Iterate though the vertices in arbitrary order.  For each vertex, connect all of its predecessors to all of its successors.

That's it.  The invariant that proves this works is that at every iteration, every vertex u is connected to every vertex v if there is a path from u to v through processed vertices.

To implement this efficiently using your adjacency-set representation, you'll need to simultaneously maintain the inverse graph, so that you can efficiently find the predecessors of any vertex.

Comment: I could actually deal without the transitive closure, I just thought that was the best way to approach this problem, thank you